# Getopt returning -1 for certain order of options

Tags: c, linux, unix, getopt

Basically getopt is returning -1 when I have a non option before the other options.

```
    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hi:o:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'i':
            ifile = optarg; 
            break;
        case 'o':
            ofile = optarg; 
            break;
        case 'h':
            printf("...");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Option\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
```

example:

```
./a.out 22 -i infile -o outfile
```

This makes getopt return -1 and the switch statement never gets executed.

```
./a.out -i infile -o outfile
```

However this works, but I really would like the first option to be just a number, and not have to include another option for it.

I thought getopt was supposed to handle this case, but I could be wrong.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to work. Options end when the first non-option is encountered -- everything from then on is supposed to be filenames.

Comment: Handling out of order arguments is a GNU extension, not Posix. Make sure you don't enforce a "strict Posix" mode anywhere.

Comment: Why don't you do `a.out -i infile -o outfile 22`?

Comment: @Barmar interesting, I didn't know that is how it was supposed to work.  I think I will just go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Universal solution

The simplest way around the problem presented is:

```
n = atoi(argv[1]);

argv[1] = argv[0];
++argv;
--argc;

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hi:o:")) != -1)
{
    ...as before...
}
```

This effectively consumes the first option and then rejigs things to the orthodox format.  This works with any version of `getopt()` that is remotely compliant with the standards (de facto and de jure).  Note that if you don't reassign `argv[1] = argv[0];`, `getopt()` will use the value in the original `argv[1]` (the number in this example) as the 'name of the program'.

#### Using GNU `getopt()`

With GNU [`getopt()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt), there are two ways to handle the problem.  One uses the 'return in order' feature so that non-option ('file name') arguments are treated as if they were prefixed by an option character code 1 (ASCII SOH control character; aka <kbd>Control-A</kbd>).  The other uses the default mode whereby `getopt()` permutes the options as it processes them.  Note that this is not available by default on Mac OS X, amongst other platforms.

This code almost does both jobs; you simply have to change the option string between the 'permute' mode (shown) and the 'return in order' mode using `"-hi:o:"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    int opt;
    char *ifile = 0;
    char *ofile = 0;

    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hi:o:")) != -1)
    {
        printf("Option: %c\n", opt);
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'i':
            ifile = optarg;
            break;
        case 'o':
            ofile = optarg;
            break;
        case 'h':
            printf("...");
            break;
        case 1:
            n = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Option %d\n", opt);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    printf("argc = %d; optind = %d\n", argc, optind);
    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    if (ifile != 0)
        printf("i-file: %s\n", ifile);
    if (ofile != 0)
        printf("o-file: %s\n", ofile);
    printf("%d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Example run with 'permute':

```
$ go9 9 -i in -o out
Option: i
Option: o
argc = 6; optind = 5
argv[5] = 9
i-file: in
o-file: out
9
$
```

Example run with 'return in order':

```
$ go9 9 -i in -o out
Option: 
Option: i
Option: o
argc = 6; optind = 6
i-file: in
o-file: out
9
$
```

Make sure you do not have environment variable POSIXLY_CORRECT set if you want this to work.  You can prefix the option string with a `+` to force POSIX-like behaviour.

Comment: Wouldn't a simpler universal solution be: `optind = 2;`? Afaics that's bog-standard posix. (Or better, `if (argc > 1) optind = 2;`

Comment: It isn't documented what happens if you go setting `optind`.  You can play with fire if you like; I'd rather ensure that the argument list is in the normal format.

Comment: It's specifically UB if you set optind to 0, and implicitly UB if you set it out of range. But any other use is clear: "The variable optind is the index of the next element of the argv[] vector to be processed." It's not otherwise magic.

Comment: Suppose you have `-abc` as an argument and option string `"ab:"`; the function knows how to return `a` and then `b` with `optarg` pointing to `"c"`; and nothing in the external interface documents how it knows to resume where it left off.  Basically, it is up to you.  I wouldn't risk it; you're welcome to dig your own grave.  You'll probably get away with it, but…

Comment: I've been getting away with it for more than three decades, so it's safe enough for me. My grave is ever closer of course, but I think I still have some time left :)

Comment: I've not tried it in the quarter century or so I've been using `getopt()`, and I don't have access to the variety of systems that I used to have, so I can't go round testing it easily.  However, if you've been doing it for that long, it probably works OK.  If it is done before you call `getopt()`, you should be clear.  One minor annoyance is that there isn't a documented way to reset the system after you've parsed one set of arguments. It's seldom a practical problem, though.

Comment: Yes, I was just referring to setting it initially, or after `getopt` increments it (which it will do after any argument or at the end of a series of non-argument options). Changing `optind` mid-parse is the case you mention, which is not clear. However, it's commonly used (not just by me) for "subsystem" argument parsing, where the first argument is the name of the subsystem.